# About divergence proof in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Prove the identity $$\text{div } (f v) = (\text{div } v) f + v \cdot \nabla f$$ where $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar function and $v:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a vector. The term $fv$ means multiplying $f$ to all the components of $v$.

I am supposed to apply the product rule and how I am I construct those partial derivatives? A hint is appreciated.

Comment: Just use the definition of divergence $\nabla\cdot(fv) = \sum_{i}^n\partial_i(fv_i)$ where $v_i$ is the ith component of $v$ and use the product rule as you said.